# Is induced emf primarily produced (only) at the cost of mechanical energy?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

A few days ago we had a physics test which included the following multiple choice question:-

*Induced emf is primarily produced at the expense of________.*

*a)Electrical Energy; (b)Mechanical energy*

Options **c** and **d** are not mentioned because they were definitely not the answers.

I ticked **b**(Mechanical energy) and indeed it was the correct answer but cannot we also use electrical energy for this purpose?

For example, let's place a loop of wire in the electric field of an electromagnet powered by a D.C. source through a rheostat. Now, if we continuously change the resistance of the rheostat there will be a continuous variation in the current supplied which in turn will cause continuous variations in the magnetic field of the electromagnet.
Now due to the continuous variations in the magnetic field, there are continuous variations in the magnetic flux through the wire.

Now we all know that changing magnetic flux induces an emf. So can't electrical energy also be a primary source of emf generation or is it that there's **mechanical work** done in varying the resistance of the rheostat too. In addition the D.C. battery supplies current due to the **chemical energy** stored in it.

Kindly clear this up. Thanks

Note: I used D.C. source instead of simply using an A.C. source because that A.C. source will also require mechanical energy for its working(by spinning the coil).

Comment: This is just a bad question in my opinion, especially if expects only one option as the answer. Yes, of course electrical energy can be (and often is) used to produce "induced emf", e.g. in transformers.

Comment: A solar cell (panel) followed by a boost converter. The induced emf in the main coil of the converter is produced without any mechanical energy involved. So, on a world where all energy is solar the correct answer would be c) electromagnetic energy. But in this world we like to spin turbines with water or vapor so...

Comment: I would agree with the previous comments and add a piece of advice... change schools. You are being asked nonsensical questions instead of being taught useful material.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course if you have an AC circuit you'll have an oscillating electric field, which will generate a magnetic field. If you have a nearby circuit you'll see an induced emf on that circuit. That's why `primarily' was added to the question. The point is that energy is the universal coin. You can exchange electrical energy with mechanical energy and vice-versa.

Comment: **"That's why `primarily' was added to the question. The point is that energy is the universal coin. You can exchange electrical energy with mechanical energy and vice-versa."**
Can you clarify this last bit of your answer. Do you mean to say that **mechanical energy** is indeed the correct answer? Also what did you infer from the word "primarily"? What do you think it means here and how can we use it to obtain the correct answer?

Comment: Yes typically an induced emf is due to motion, where the magnetic flux varies as the area is changing. For example a rotating coil through which a magnetic field is passing. Basically how a generator works, where mechanical work (due to for example a thermodynamical engine) turns into electrical energy. Option b) is the correct one.

Comment: Can you please also take a look at this:-
"Can't the changing magnetic field also be produced by an **electromagnet** that is powerd by a **current from a D.C.** source through a rheostat as I described in the body of my question. In the case I described, the primary source used to induce the emf is, I think, the **changing current** from the D.C. source which in turn changes the magnetic field of the electromagnet continuously."

Comment: Yes as long as you have changing magnetic flux, either by mechanical means (area change) or electrical means (magnetic field change), you'll get induced emf. The latter is what you suggested while the former is  the typical situation in a generator.

Answer (score 0):

Induced EMF is the EMF from induction (that is: because of a changing magnetic field), which would exclude sources of EMF like the potential difference across a chemical battery, solar cell, thermocouple, or capacitor.

Comment: "Induced EMF is the EMF from induction (that is: because of a changing magnetic field)"
But can't the changing magnetic field also be produced by an electromagnet that is powerd by a **current** from a D.C. source through a rheostat as I described in the body of my question.
In the case I described, the primary source used to induce the emf is, I think, the **changing current** from the D.C. source which in turn changes the magnetic field of the electromagnet continuously.

Comment: @MuhammadFahadIqbalKhan Yes, that's right. I misunderstood that part of your question, so my answer isn't really relevant, I apologize.